# Jquerymobile anchor tag issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile. and in it anchor tag always add a # value before requesting url. so that first default page of website runs and then next page is added in dom. but in my case anchor tags are not adding hash values. how can i add them.

this is my page's head section

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Don't use rel=external attribute with anchor tag, If you are used
You can also use on click event : $.mobile.changePage($("#pageid"), "flip", true, true);
$("#anchortagid").live("click",function(event){
if(event.handled !== true){ 
    $.mobile.changePage("#pageid", {transition: "slide"});

}
   return false;
});
```